# cannot find attribute in imported file

Tags: python, import, tkinter, attributeerror

I am trying to make a button interface for my program which is imported as rlg. rlg has a live graphing system in which two variables can be measured and updated as the generations of the simulation go on. I want to be able to make these two variables selective so i made a dictionary 'graphLines' in the main() method of rlg in which each string selection on the drop down menu acts as a key. However i dont seem to be able to access it and get the error message: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'graphLines'. Can anyone see what i am doing wrong.

```
from Tkinter import *
import runlivegraph3 as rlg

def run():
    rlg.main()

def setLine1(name):
    rlg.main.Line1data = rlg.main.graphLines[name] #graphlines is a dictionary in runlivegraph3 main method

def setLine2(name):
    rlg.main.Line2data = rlg.main.graphLines[name]


root = Tk()

var1 = StringVar()
var1.set("select graph line 1 data") #initial variable in drop down menu, each string is a key in the graphLines dictionary
op1 = OptionMenu(root, var1, 'Political attacks in turn',
                 'Ethnic attacks in turn',
                 'Total attacks in turn',
                 'Ethnic attacks as a percentage of total attacks',
                 'Political attacks as a percentage of total attacks',
                 'Group 1 ethnic antagonism',
                 'Group 2 ethnic antagonism',
                 command = setLine1).pack()


var2 = StringVar()
var2.set("select graph line 2 data") #initial variable in drop down menu
op2 = OptionMenu(root, var2, 'Political attacks in turn',
                 'Ethnic attacks in turn',
                 'Total attacks in turn',
                 'Ethnic attacks as a percentage of total attacks',
                 'Political attacks as a percentage of total attacks',
                 'Group 1 ethnic antagonism',
                 'Group 2 ethnic antagonism',
                 command = setLine2).pack()
butn = Button(root, text = 'run',  command = run)
butn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

this is the main() function of the program i am importing in the Tkinter button program

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import sys, random, time, csv
def main():

IDs = {}
boardDims = (20,20)
Line1data = None
Line2data = None
turnLimit = 40
pause = 0.0001

ethnicPred = []
politicalPred = []
totalAttacks = []
generation = []
data1 = []
data2 = []
data3 = []
ethAnt1 = []
ethAnt2 = []
polAnt1 = []
polAnt2 = []
EthnicAttacksInTurn = []
PoliticalAttacksInTurn = []
TotalAttacksInTurn = []
ProportionEth = []
ProportionPol = []


board = make_board(boardDims)

finallyAddAgents(IDs, board, boardDims)
splitAgents(IDs)
setRemainingPolitics(IDs)
setPoliticalAntagonism(IDs)

turn = 0
line1, = plot(turn, 0, 'b')  #initialise lines
line2, = plot(turn, 0, 'r')
running = 1
while running:
    ion()   #sets up graph base and axes
    axes()
    xlim(0,turnLimit)
    ylim(0,30)
    if turn == turnLimit: running = 0
    print_board3(IDs, board, boardDims)
    print 'turn ', str(turn)
    polAttackTurn = []
    ethAttackTurn = []
    AllAgentsPerformActions(IDs, board,turn,ethnicPred, politicalPred,
                            totalAttacks,polAttackTurn,ethAttackTurn)

    totalAttackTurn = sum(ethAttackTurn) + sum(polAttackTurn)
    if totalAttackTurn != 0:
        propEth = (sum(ethAttackTurn)*100)/totalAttackTurn
        propPol = (sum(polAttackTurn)*100)/totalAttackTurn        
    if totalAttackTurn == 0:
        propEth = 0
        propPol = 0
    TotalAttacksInTurn.append(totalAttackTurn)
    EthnicAttacksInTurn.append(sum(ethAttackTurn))
    PoliticalAttacksInTurn.append(sum(polAttackTurn))
    ProportionEth.append(propEth)
    ProportionPol.append(propPol)



    k =  sum(politicalPred)
    j = sum(ethnicPred)
    #f = sum(totalAttacks)
    #print k, j, f
    data1.append(j)
    data2.append(k)
    #data3.append(f)
    generation.append(turn)
    for agent in IDs.values():
        if agent.group == '1':
            ethAnt1.append(agent.antagonism['2'])
            break
    for agent in IDs.values():
        if agent.group == '2':
            ethAnt2.append(agent.antagonism['1'])
            break
    for agent in IDs.values():
        if agent.politics == 'A':
            polAnt1.append(agent.polAntagonism['B'])
            break
    for agent in IDs.values():
        if agent.politics == 'B':
            polAnt2.append(agent.polAntagonism['A'])
            break
    #this is the dictionary i am trying to access from the Tkinter button program
    graphLines = {'Political attacks in turn':sum(polAttackTurn),
              'Ethnic attacks in turn':sum(ethAttackTurn),
              'Total attacks in turn':totalAttackTurn,
              'Ethnic attacks as a percentage of total attacks': propEth,
              'Political attacks as a percentage of total attacks': propPol,
              'Group 1 ethnic antagonism': ethAnt1[-1],
              'Group 2 ethnic antagonism': ethAnt2[-1]}

        line1.set_ydata(append(line1.get_ydata(), Line1data))
        line1.set_xdata(append(line1.get_xdata(), turn))
        line2.set_ydata(append(line2.get_ydata(), Line2data))
        line2.set_xdata(append(line2.get_xdata(), turn))
        draw()
        turn += 1
```

Comment: What in the world made you think you can access a variable of a function as an *attribute* of that function? I can't even imagine what you think this is going to do, or what you're trying to do, with such a construction.

Comment: so i cannot access the graphLines dictionary from the button file? I have not been taught programming properly so i only have a vague notion of what 'attribute' means.

Comment: Well, it's not indented properly, but assuming your `graphLines =` line is intended to be inside your `main()` function, `graphLines` is a local variable in that function. The dictionary exists only while `main()` is running and is discarded when the function ends.

Comment: And whatever Python tutorial you are following to learn Python should explain the meaning of `attribute`.

Comment: so the only accessible variables have to be global? then how come Line1data and Line2data do not throw the same exception?

Comment: Because in setLine1 and setLine2, you set an attribute on the function, like: `def spam(): pass` followed by `spam.eggs = 5`.
This gives the function object an attribute, but it does not become a  local variable within the function.

Comment: ok cant put the dict outside the mainloop as i need the arrays in the dict to be emptied at each loop. i can put them as strings but is there a way to remove the apostraphies that designate a string, i know that for the majority of elements i can do int() but two of the elements are arrays.

Comment: also i cant have the general integer elements outside the mainloop as they too need to be changed with each loop and will also throw a 'referenced before assignment' error

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd better turn my comment into an answer, so here I go.

You are getting confused between the difference between variables and attributes, so I'll explain the difference with some examples. Your question is not a matter of importing actually, but more about scope and object oriented programming (OOP).

**(e.g. 1)** To set a local variable within a function, you can do:

```
def spam():
    eggs = 5
```

**(e.g. 2)** To set an attribute on a function object (which is usually not so logical), you can do:

```
def spam():
    pass
spam.eggs = 5
```

While these may appear to be similar, their effect is very different. In the first example, `eggs` is a local variable within the function `spam`. Local variables are created, accessed, and modified *only* within their defining function.

```
def spam():
    eggs = 5
print spam.eggs
```

will result in an error, however

```
def spam():
    pass
spam.eggs = 5
print spam.eggs
```

will not. In the second example, `eggs` is an attribute of the function (object) `spam`. It can be created, accessed, and modified both within a method of the object or outside the object, but *not* within the function itself as a local variable (also because the function does not know of its existence until it is fully defined). Therefore, the following would raise an error:

```
def spam():
    print eggs
spam.eggs = 5
spam()
```

because `eggs` is an attribute, not a local variable.

### If you are familiar with OOP, here is some expansion:

The first example would be equivalent to:

```
class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self):
        eggs = 5
```

while the second example would be equivalent to:

```
class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.eggs = 5
```

In terms of OOP, the difference is simply that the first sets a local variable, while the second sets an instance variable. Trying to do `Spam().eggs` on the first class would not make sense, while on the second it could.

### Finally,

To solve your problem, either define the variables you need outside of a function, or use the `global` keyword to show that they are global. Example usage:

```
def spam():
    global eggs
    eggs = 5
spam()
print eggs  # Prints 5
```